# Vuetify clickable icon inside data-table doesn't change pointer style

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` like this one:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.iron>
        <v-icon @click.native="getDocument">mdi-download</v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

but whenever I move the mouse over the download icon it doesn't change its style from pointer to hand but I don't know why. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `@click.native`. Vuetify won't be able to understnad that you have a `click` listener. Under the hood Vuetify has something like this:

```
<div class="icon icon-x" :styles="styles"/>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
       styles() {
         const base = {};

         if (this.$listeners.click) base.cursor = 'pointer';

         return base;
       }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Of course, things are a litle bit more complicated than that. To resolve your issue you can either use `@click` or add a utility class to the icon:

```
.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

...

<v-icon class="cursor-pointer" @click.native="getDocument">mdi-download</v-icon>
```

Comment: I changed the code to simply use `@click` ;) thank you